# Command to distinguish a table from a view

Tags: sql, presto, dbeaver

Is there a command to determine whether a given relation is a `table` or a `view`?

The trial-and-error method I'm using is to do:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW table_name
```

If it's a `table`, not a `view`, my database software (Presto in DBeaver) will give me an error:

> Relation `table_name` is a `table`, not a `view`

I presume this error is coming from a similar command being run internally to vet my query. If it's a `view`, the command of course works.

Comment: If you are using `SHOW CREATE ..` then you **are** targeting a specific database engine - that is non-standard SQL

Comment: The standard way to query metadata is the [Information Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema). Whether *your* database system implements it I couldn't say. Also, note, that as much as possible, you *shouldn't* distinguish between tables and views. You should be able to replace a table with a view (or vice versa) and not invalidate existing code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will show a table of information about all tables available, including which are `view`s and which are `table`s:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

See [Information Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql) for more details.

Comment: caveat that if your datastore is large, querying `information_schema` can be slow, so you'll do well to specify `where table_schema = '{schema}'` and even `where table_name = '{table}'`

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use column 'Type' in Sys.Objects to differentiate a Table or View. If value in column Type is 'V' then its a View, otherwise if value in column Type is 'U' then its a table

To check if it is a table use below query

`SELECT DISTINCT NAME, O.TYPE FROM SYS.OBJECTS O WHERE O.NAME LIKE 'Prefix%' AND O.TYPE='U'`

To check if it is a view use below query

`SELECT DISTINCT NAME, O.TYPE FROM SYS.OBJECTS O WHERE O.NAME LIKE 'Prefix%' AND O.TYPE='V'`